# How to paste content of a file before glimmering cursor in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

There is a file with some text. Names of packages which I want to delete. And I need to paste content of this file to apt purge {here's content of my file} How can I do that?

I have no GUI, only tty.

Thanks. Command Substitution helped me.

```
apt purge `cat myfile.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do that. You can use for that `bash` feature called `command substitution`. It basically substitutes particular element in one command with the result of execution of another command.

In your particular case you may use simple `for loop` substituting list of files it should iterate through with `cat file` which displays the content of your file. I assume you have a list of packages where each of them is placed on a separate line.

`` for i in `cat file`; do apt purge $i; done ``

You may want to add to it `sudo` to be able to perform the required operation:

`` for i in `cat file`; do sudo apt purge $i; done ``

Comment: You should not read the lines of a file with `for`: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a for loop to cycle through your file and execute the necessary command on the line.

```
file=“/path/to/file”
while IFS= read -r line
do
     apt-get purge “$line”
done <“$file”
```

The IFS= option will prevent leading/trailing white space and the -r will prevent backslash escapes from being interpreted.
The while loop will cycle through each line until the end of the file. At the end, you are feeding in the input file for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `xargs` command is useful here:

```
xargs apt-get purge < myfile.txt
```